# javascript - bypassing iframe cross domain security

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm trying to figure out a way around cross-domain security with iframes and javascript.

We have several publisher sites that have our simple javascript file (served via Amazon CloudFront) that is directly embedded on their sites. The script does a few things on the publishers site (modifies the DOM) to display a static ad that we position differently for each publisher site.

When we serve this same script through an iframe (Google DFP) it obviously does not work due to cross domain security as the iframe URL and the publisher site URL are not relevant.

Now another ad server we use, to get around that they have an HTML file each publisher hosts (so relative path for each pub would be something like /iframe-buster.html) that contains some javascript which allows the ad to expand outside of the iframe. I don't understand exactly what it does by my thoughts are:

1. Ad served via iframe creates a subiframe with the URL path to the iframe buster
2. The new iframe URL contains a query string variable (such as ad identifier)
3. The iframe JS then can modify the documents DOM by calling parent.parent or top.?

I have no idea if this would work, does anyone know or attempted something like this before?

Answer (score 1):

The script hosted on the publisher site need not (in fact should not) bust the iframe. Instead the purpose of this script is to establish a communication channel between the AD iframe (hosted inside DFP) and the publisher page.

The catch here is - At runtime the script on the pub page knows what is the DFP iframe url domain but the script served through cloudfront does not know what is the publisher page url because of cross domain access restriction.

So the publisher script can set a postMessage handler to receive messages from the ad Iframe. It can do something similar to this

```
        function registerPostMessageHandler() {
            // Listen to message from child window
            var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
            var eventer = window[eventMethod];
            var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

            eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {
                var key = e.message ? "message" : "data";
                var data = e[key];
                console.log("Message obtained from origin " + e.origin + ' data: ' + data);

                //Insert an AD slot based on the message
            },false);
        }
```

and the JS in AD iframe can do

```
parent.postMessage(/*where to create the AD slot*/);
```

**Note:** "Ad served via iframe creates a subiframe with the URL path to the iframe buster" - is not possible because the iframe does not know the publisher domain and because of security restriction it can't figure out either.